# Illustrating a matrix assembly within the array environment

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I'm having trouble aligning the parentheses of a matrix assembly (parentheses within the same matrix). Essentially, what I want to do is this (excuse the terrible paint-job):

[image]

Where the submatrix K1 and K2 overlap. K1 and K2, should be 6x6, and therefore the assembly is a 9x9 matrix. I'm primarily familiar with the array environment: is this a possibility there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some ideas: make 3 by 3 matrices, with large entries; in appropriate spots put smashed the matrices *K*<sup>1</sup> and *K*<sup>2</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,delarray}

\newcommand{\lK}[1]{%
  \text{\LARGE$K^{#1}$}%
}
\newcommand{\plK}{\phantom{\lK{1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrlap{\smash[b]{%
  \begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}ccc@{}}\rbrack
  \plK&\plK&\plK\\[3ex]
  \plK&
              \lK{1}&
  \plK\\[3ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK
  \end{array}
}}
  \plK&\plK&\plK&\plK&\plK\\[2ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK&\plK&\plK\\[2ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK&\plK&\plK
\mathllap{\smash[b]{%
  \begin{array}[t]\lbrack{@{}ccc@{}}\rbrack
  \plK&\plK&\plK\\[3ex]
  \plK&
              \lK{2}&
  \plK\\[3ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK
  \end{array}
}}\\[2ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK&\plK&\plK\\[2ex]
  \plK&\plK&\plK&\plK&\plK\\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the environment `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
    \Block{3-3}{K^1} &&&&\\\
    \\
    &&\Block{3-3}{K^2} \\
    \\
    \hspace*{5mm}&\hspace*{5mm}&\hspace*{5mm}&\hspace*{5mm}&\hspace*{5mm}\\
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-3}]
    \SubMatrix[{3-3}{5-5}]
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]